# $product->getProductUrl() returns URL without category prefix

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls, redirect-url

I tried to enable the category **prefix** from admin  `STORES >> CONFIG >> CATALOG >> CATALOG >> SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION`.
It is working pretty well on the category page.
I am using Magenest Shop by brand extension for the brand's page and on these brand pages the URL of products looks like abc.com//product but on the category page, it shows like `abc.com/category/product`.
I already tried indexing and cache flush.
Please let me know if there is anything else I can try

My Magento version is 2.3.1

Comment: Looks like it is a module bug. It works normally for categories but not for brands and brands is a @magenest module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a product coud be in multiple categories, this is exactly what is supposed to do.

When you browse a category a current category prefix is added to product url.

Shop by brand page is not a category page so no prefix is added by default.

If the extension doesn't provide this functionality, you could ask the extension support to introduce it in the next version or customize it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @krybbio you saved my day. The brand page was not a category page so the `current_category` was unable to fetch the category.